# My JavaScript function isn't using one of the variables i need it to

Tags: javascript, mongoose, this

I'm creating a mongoose schema and need to do required checks a lot, so I tried creating this function. But it says that 'subcategory' is initialized but never used. How can I get the function to check this. like I need it to?

```
function requiredCheck(subcategory, value) {
  return this.subcategory === value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket accessors to check a property of `this` by variable:

```
function requiredCheck(subcategory, value) {
  return this[subcategory] === value;
}
```

Otherwise you're checking for the property with the literal key "subcategory" which probably isn't what you want.